# Why is the link formatting on my question not working as expected?

Tags: bug, specific-question, formatting

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337518/update-model-from-database-not-finding-db-some-functions) and it looks like the links aren't formatting properly.

I suspect the problem comes from the `.` at the end of the first url (even though it's part of it for real) but if not, then what's wrong with my formatting?

Comment: I've noticed quite a few URLs recently that have random junk appended onto the end, just like the first link in your question. It doesn't seem to be part of the URL itself and, in my experience, can be safely removed.

Comment: Interesting. Apparently the URL parser doesn't like unmatched parentheses in URLs, replacing the unmatched parenthesis with `%28` (url encoding it) seems to have fixed the issue, but this seems like something that should be addressed.

Comment: @F1Krazy That's not junk but a scroll to text fragment. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161819/what-exactly-is-the-text-location-hash-in-an-url). These can be helpful for long pages.

Comment: @Nick You shouldn't? You might want to post a new answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13225028/7296893), afaik they're allowed after the `?` even though I tend to encode them when creating urls just to be sure.

Comment: @ErikA Pretty sure that answer already says that you can use them as such in the query part, i.e., not in the rest. The ones in OPs URL aren't part of the query

Comment: @Nick Nope, they're part of the `# fragment`, as described in [rfc3986 appendix A](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A), where subdelimiters are also allowed. While the answer doesn't state that, the spec it refers to does.

Comment: @ErikA Huh, TIL, I shall make sure to flame my employers for telling me to remove paren.s from my URLs :p